# How do I work with touching geometry?

Tags: modeling, snapping

Okay, I'm making something organic; a paw. The problem is, the toes of a paw touch. How do I make them touch and not go through each other. How do I then prevent removing doubles from merging touching toes, but still use that feature? I can't find the search terms I need for this subject. If someone could give me a means to find tutorials or other help on how to do this, that would be great.

Thank you very much for any help. :)

Comment: Not much of an organic modeler myself, but as far as I know stopping self intersections, and dealing with self collisions in animation is not a trivial task, posing challenges even for professional high-end professionals. To my knowledge perfect tangency is generally avoided, in favor of very-close-by-but-not-quite intersections. In organic models should not be very noticeable. Also play with the threshold value of the *remove doubles* operator